# timed-out waiting for login prompt Telnet Perl

Tags: regex, perl, telnet

I have a problem to log in into a telnet prompt using perl

this is my prompt:

```
Trying 192.168.10.15...
Connected to 192.168.10.15.
Escape character is '^]'.

Enter username and password
>
```

And this is my code:

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Port => 11052, Timeout => 10, Prompt => '/Enter username and password/ /\n/ /> $/i');
$t->open("192.168.10.15");
$t->login('test', 'test1');
@lines = $t->cmd("ls");
print @lines;
```

But I have a message error: timed-out waiting for login prompt

I tried using:

```
$t->waitfor('/Enter username and password/ /\n/ /> $/i');
```

and

```
$->waitfor('/> $/i');
```

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem :D

It works for me using:

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Host=> "192.168.10.15", Port => 11052, Timeout => 5, Prompt => "/Enter username and password/");    
$t->waitfor('/Enter username and password/'); 
$t->print('test test1');
```

In my case the sentence `$t->login('test', 'test1');` doesn't work, then I tried writing usr and pw on the same line `$t->print('test test1');` and it works!